# Rails HAML conditional link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, dry

Good day, i have this kind of code:

```
= link_to some_url do
  PLENTY OF MARKUP HERE
```

Now i need to make this link optional, so if condition is not met i need plain MARKUP to be printed, so first anti-DRY solution:

```
- if condition
  = link_to some_url do
    PLENTY OF MARKUP HERE
-else
  PLENTY OF MARKUP HERE REPEATED :(
```

Another solution if to put `PLENTY OF MARKUP` into partial, so i winder if where is another simple solution without partial ? I tried this one:

```
= link_to_if condition?, some_url do
  PLENTY OF MARKUP HERE
```

but unfortunately `link_to_if` does not work as expected here.

Comment: if i got you, you want by clicking the link render another template?

Answer (score 1):

`link_to_if` uses the block for a different purpose compared to `link_to`. So it cannot do what you want.

You can define your own helper to do what you want.

If you only need to do this a few times, instead of using a custom helper, you can instead save the result of a block (the `PLENTY OF MARKUP`) to a local variable, to make it easy for you to use it repeatedly. For example:

```
- plentyofmarkup = do
  PLENTY OF MARKUP HERE

- if condition
  = link_to (raw plentyofmarkup), some_url
- else
  = raw plentyofmarkup
```

Or alternatively:

```
= link_to_if condition, (raw plentyofmarkup), some_url
```

Note that the `raw` function is used to stop Rails from escaping the string automatically.

To define your own helper method, try:

```
def link_to_if_do condition, options = {}, html_options = {}
  blockresult = yield
  link_to_if condition, blockresult, options, html_options
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own conditional link helper, and put it in application_helper:

```
def conditional_link_to( condition, url, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block ) do
  if condition
    link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
  else
    if block_given?
      block.arity <= 1 ? capture(name, &block) : capture(name, options, html_options, &block)
    else
      name
    end
  end
end
```

This is largely taken from [link_to_unless](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless), but modified to pass the block to link_to. I've not tested this, but it should be enough to give you an idea. :)